# How do I access my ubuntu server from anywhere in the world?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

How do I remotely access Ubuntu server 18.04.1

Right now I have Ubuntu server 18.04.1 set up, and I use puTTY to access it from my  laptop. I want be able to access it though puTTY or ssh or something from anywhere in the world. Do I have to port forward my router to be able to access it remotely? Should I not be using puTTY to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there have a couple of solution to do this:

1. port forward on your router

   - if you choose this way do not forward the standard ssh port on your router on the port 22 normally have a lot of attempt to access your server by use some vulnerability, if you forward external port 2222 -> 22 this should be avoided (but spend anyway some time for secure your server). Also you have to know your external IP address. If your ip is static you can also choose to create a domain name (for free DNS registration you can search freenom) or if is dynamic IP address use some service for DDNS to have domain name updated whit the IP address of your router.
2. Use a VPN which allow you to reach your server like you are in local network, this do not require to perform a port forward is more secure but is more complex to be implemented